# How to use to 2 created partitions on a server

Tags: linux, partition

I created a hosting server and 2 partitions where created

```
/dev/sda4   
2 857 629.99 MB

/dev/sdb1   
2 816 541.60 MB
```

when one partitions gets filled does the server  automatically use the next partition?  or what will happened get it gets filled and the next part. is empty.

or should I use one partition because when 1 partition gets filled it will NOT use the space on the next partition

I don't use RAID because I have all my backup locally

Answer (score 0):

It depends....

Your server typically doesn’t write data directly to partitions, you first need to create a file system.

You can create **two file systems**, one on each partition and then you control where you write what data (by mounting each file system on a different mount point) and once a file system (the partition) becomes full trying to store more data there will result in an error.

Alternatively you can use the two partitions as the physical storage for the linux Logical Volume Manager LVM. With LVM you can use both your partitions to create a **single file system** or if your server is already using LVM you can even use the new partitions to **increase existing file system(s)** and you can continue to write data until both partitions are completely full.

Comment: I have CENT0S 7   and it created those partitions  on two hard drives sda1 and sdb1  I just want to know if it will use the space on both partitions or do I have to extend 1 o get more space